# arch linux cannot mount /boot/EFI unknown file system vfat

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, boot, mount, uefi

I got that error on arch linux after booting: `cannot mount /boot/EFI unknown file system vfat`. I downgraded the kernel and now everything works, but what should I do now? How do I fix this?

EDIT: following [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=194797) thread I tried to upgrade my system and run `mkinitcpio` and I got this error: `==> ERROR: '/lib/modules/6.0.12-arch1-1' is not a valid kernel module directory`. I upgraded to `linux-6.1.1.arch1-1`...

Comment: Did you built your kernel yourself? With the kernel where this *does not work*, run `grep vfat /proc/filesystems` and `modprobe vfat` and add the `dmesg` output that appears after running the last modprobe command.

Comment: Your new kernel installation seems to be broken: you're missing its modules tree.

Comment: Just like if `make install` was run, but `make modules_install` was not.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot. Run uname -a. Are you running 6.0.12 or 6.1.1? If 6.1.1, run pacman -S linux (reinstall it). Should run mkinitcpio as part of the re-install.

ALWAYS reboot after you upgrade. ALWAYS.